# Travel with a connection: what rules should I use?

Tags: covid-19, connecting-flights

I have a flight next week from Ukraine to France with 1 hour connection in Germany.

For the passengers arriving to France from Ukraine a covid test is mandatory. For the passengers arriving from the Germany to France no tests are required. There is also no need for tests from Ukraine to Germany.

Lufthansa's web site where I can check regulations do not have `transit` airports so I imagine that I need to verify Ukraine -> Germany -> France and not Ukraine -> France.

[image]

I thought about calling Lufthansa but even if they tell me by phone that I don't need to do the test the local agent at check-in desk can have a different opinion and if we call again to Lufthansa we can have again a new agent with a different opinion.

What rules apply in this case?

Comment: The first and the final embarkation points are typically the most important, especially when a very brief transit is involved, try inputting your travel details into Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true and/or IATA https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Comment: You could perhaps ask the relevant customer support person to send you an email? But if you concerned about a local agent making difficulties, do you think answers on this site have a better chance of swaying them?

Comment: Get a test, just in case. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: I have a triple vaccination and I'm not very exited with the idea of spending time and money for the test when it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 6):

As you travel from Ukraine to France, and testing is required for that travel, get tested, even when the airline is not bothered about checking it.

You do not test for the airline but to protect the people in the country you go to.

And be aware that testing requirements can change any moment.

(We had a [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169462/can-someone-unvaccinated-travel-from-the-uk-to-france-via-switzerland) recently about travel from the UK via Switzerland to France where the conclusion was that keeping to the UK to France rules made the most sense, my personal interpretation.)

PS. If testing had been required for Germany but not for France, I would still have suggested to get tested. I might even go as far as advising a self test if you do not need an official test, just to be sure you are covid free while traveling.

Comment: (+1) In my mind, it's even more obvious with a 1h transit.

Comment: Good idea about the self test, I'll consider a salivary one